# Scala - string modification in a functional manner

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm just starting Scala and so getting my head around doing things in a more functional style.

Just wondering if there is a more functional way to achieve something like the following:

```
def expand(exp: String): String = {
  var result = exp
  for ((k,v) <- libMap) {result = result.replace(k, "(%s)".format(v))}
  result
}
```

Or in general terms, given a string and some iterable collection, go through the collection and for every element, incrementally modify the input string.

Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally the pattern

```
var result = init
for (foo <- bar) { result = f(result, foo)}
result
```

can be expressed functionally as

```
bar.foldLeft(init)(f)
```

So for your case this becomas:

```
libMap.foldLeft(exp){ case(result, (k,v)) => result.replace(k, "(%s)".format(v))}
```