# why use foldLeft instead of procedural version?

Tags: scala

So in reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447061/scala-string-modification-in-a-functional-manner) it was pointed out that instead of the procedural code:

```
def expand(exp: String, replacements: Traversable[(String, String)]): String = {
  var result = exp
  for ((oldS, newS) <- replacements)
    result = result.replace(oldS, newS)
  result
}
```

You could write the following functional code:

```
def expand(exp: String, replacements: Traversable[(String, String)]): String = {
  replacements.foldLeft(exp){
    case (result, (oldS, newS)) => result.replace(oldS, newS)
  }
}
```

I would almost certainly write the first version because coders familiar with either procedural or functional styles can easily read and understand it, while only coders familiar with functional style can easily read and understand the second version.

But setting readability aside for the moment, is there something that makes `foldLeft` a better choice than the procedural version? I might have thought it would be more efficient, but it turns out that the [implementation of foldLeft](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_8_1_final/src//library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala#L174) is actually just the procedural code above. So is it just a style choice, or is there a good reason to use one version or the other?

**Edit:** Just to be clear, I'm not asking about other functions, just `foldLeft`. I'm perfectly happy with the use of `foreach`, `map`, `filter`, etc. which all map nicely onto for-comprehensions.

**Answer:** There are really two good answers here (provided by [delnan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395760/delnan) and [Dave Griffith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372283/dave-griffith)) even though I could only accept one:

- Use `foldLeft` because there are additional optimizations, e.g. using a while loop which will be faster than a for loop.
- Use `fold` if it ever gets added to regular collections, because that will make the transition to parallel collections trivial.

Comment: *"while only functional coders can easily read and understand the second version"*. Err, what? You mean **YOU** cannot (at the moment) understand the second version!

Comment: No really I don't mean that. The emphasis should be on "easily". Do you really believe that if I took a random Java coder off the street showed them the above two versions of the code, they would say that the foldLeft version was easier to understand?

Comment: Only just bumped into this question 5 years later... Programming is a team sport.  If you program in a functional setting then your playbook says, "If I need to 'sum up' something I should think some sort of fold".  If a functional programmer comes across expand v1 they have to figure out what it does.  If they come across expand v2 they know there is some sort of summation going on.  The Java programmer off the street has a playbook but missing the extra pages functional programming adds. (Show a Java program to a non-programmer.  Same effect.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's shorter and clearer - yes, you need to know what a fold is to understand it, but when you're programming in a language that's 50% functional, you should know these basic building blocks anyway. A fold is exactly what the procedural code does (repeatedly applying an operation), but it's given a name and generalized. And while it's only a small wheel you're reinventing, but it's still a wheel reinvention.

And in case the implementation of foldLeft *should* ever get some special perk - say, extra optimizations - you get that for free, without updating countless methods.

Comment: I guess the point about future optimizations of `foldLeft` is good, though it's hard to imagine what kind of optimizations those might be...

Comment: On second thought, one optimization would be to use a `while` loop, which would typically be faster than `foreach`. I looked at it and IndexedSeqOptimized uses a tail-recursive definition of `foldLeft` which is probably about as efficient as the while loop. So I guess I'm sold on the extra optimizations argument. ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Other than a distaste for mutable variable (even mutable locals), the basic reason to use fold in this case is clarity, with occasional brevity.  Most of the wordiness of the fold version is because you have to use an explicit function definition with a destructuring bind.  If each element in the list is used precisely once in the fold operation (a common case), this can be simplified to use the short form.  Thus the classic definition of the sum of a collection of numbers

```
collection.foldLeft(0)(_+_)
```

is much simpler and shorter than any equivalent imperative construct.

One additional meta-reason to use functional collection operations, although not directly applicable in this case, is to enable a move to using parallel collection operations if needed for performance.  Fold can't be parallelized, but often fold operations can be turned into commutative-associative reduce operations, and those can be parallelized.  With Scala 2.9, changing something from non-parallel functional to parallel functional utilizing multiple processing cores can sometimes be as easy as dropping a `.par` onto the collection you want to execute parallel operations on.

Comment: But not as simple as `collection.sum`. ;-)

Comment: So in Scala 2.9, what will happen with `foldLeft` in a parallel collection?

Comment: I believe that `foldLeft` and  `foldRight` just punt to the sequential implementation.  Given their generality, there's not much else they can do.  On the other hand, there is also a `fold` method on parallel collections.  It requires that the operation takes two elements of the same type as the collection, and assumes that the operation is associative. This will try to automatically parallelize the operation over any available cores.

Comment: Interesting. I see that `fold` exists on parallel collections but [the implementation is still sequential](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/src/library/scala/collection/parallel/mutable/ParArray.scala#L179). But I can imagine that [the restricted definition](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/scala/collection/parallel/ParIterableLike.html) allows for a parallel implementation that you can't do with with `foldLeft`. Seems like `fold` should be added to non-parallel collections to make the transition to parallel ones seamless...

Comment: Hmm, I had assumed that the parallelization was already done.  Looks like it's not there yet.

Comment: Parallelizing folds is [problematic](http://labs.oracle.com/projects/plrg/Publications/ICFPAugust2009Steele.pdf). ("Organizing Functional Code for Parallel Execution; or, foldl and foldr Considered Slightly Harmful." 2MB PDF, but it's Guy Steele, it's worth it!)

Answer (score 8):

One word I haven't seen mentioned here yet is **[declarative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming)**:

> Declarative programming is often defined as any style of programming that is not imperative. A number of other common definitions exist that attempt to give the term a definition other than simply contrasting it with imperative programming. For example:
>
> - A program that **describes what computation should be performed** and **not how** to compute it
> - Any programming language that lacks side effects (or more specifically, is referentially transparent)
> - A language with a clear correspondence to mathematical logic.
>
> These definitions overlap substantially.

Higher-order functions (HOFs) are a key enabler of declarativity, since we only specify the *what* (e.g. "using this collection of values, multiply each value by 2, sum the result") and not the *how* (e.g. initialize an accumulator, iterate with a for loop, extract values from the collection, add to the accumulator...).

Compare the following:

```
// Sugar-free Scala (Still better than Java<5)
def sumDoubled1(xs: List[Int]) = {
  var sum = 0                     // Initialized correctly?
  for (i <- 0 until xs.size) {    // Fenceposts?
    sum = sum + (xs(i) * 2)       // Correct value being extracted? 
                                  // Value extraction and +/* smashed together
  }       
  sum                             // Correct value returned?
}

// Iteration sugar (similar to Java 5)
def sumDoubled2(xs: List[Int]) = {
  var sum = 0
  for (x <- xs)          // We don't need to worry about fenceposts or 
    sum = sum + (x * 2)  // value extraction anymore; that's progress
  sum                               
}

// Verbose Scala
def sumDoubled3(xs: List[Int]) = xs.map((x: Int) => x*2). // the doubling
                                    reduceLeft((x: Int, y: Int) => x+y) // the addition

// Idiomatic Scala
def sumDoubled4(xs: List[Int]) = xs.map(_*2).reduceLeft(_+_)
//                                       ^ the doubling  ^
//                                                       \ the addition
```

Note that our first example, `sumDoubled1`, is already more declarative than (most would say superior to) C/C++/Java<5 for loops, because we haven't had to micromanage the iteration state and termination logic, but we're still vulnerable to off-by-one errors.

Next, in `sumDoubled2`, we're basically at the level of Java>=5.  There are still a couple things that can go wrong, but we're getting pretty good at reading this code-shape, so errors are quite unlikely.  **However**, don't forget that a pattern that's trivial in a toy example isn't always so readable when scaled up to production code!

With `sumDoubled3`, desugared for didactic purposes, and `sumDoubled4`, the idiomatic Scala version, the iteration, initialization, value extraction and choice of return value are all gone.

Sure, it takes time to learn to read the functional versions, but we've drastically foreclosed our options for making mistakes.  The "business logic" is clearly marked, and the plumbing is chosen from the same menu that everyone else is reading from.

Comment: I'm not sure I see how this all applies. I would describe both the procedural version and the functional version as "given a collection and an initial string, repeatedly apply replace on the string given the replacement values in the collection". Could you translate them into your terms and explain how the first version is "how" and the second version is "what"?

Comment: Note also that both versions of the function are side effect free. It's perfectly natural (and common) to write functions that are side effect free but have procedural implementations.

Comment: Sure, your version happens to be side effect free, but there are a lot of tokens to read, and as the code complexity increases, the chance that references to mutable state might sneak into your closure increases.

Comment: I still don't get what you mean by "declarative". The code you added above just argues that it's good to reuse existing function definitions. But that's true no matter what kind of code you write...

Comment: Declarative: Please turn off the light and close the door.

Imperative: Please get out of bed, walk over to the lightswitch, raise your arm such that the lightswitch is within reach of your fingers, grasp the lightswitch with two fingers...

Declarativity is closely related to reuse.

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to translate all your metaphors into actual code guidelines. Can you explain what's the "light" and what's the "bed" in the question at hand?

Comment: My narrative is unrelated to the "problem" domain, it's just a metaphor for thinking about declarative programming.  With traditional imperative programming, we often have to describe a computation in painstaking detail, and our options for reuse are limited because of the paucity of abstraction mechanisms available in our languages.

Comment: Steve: your code is not declarative because it uses "var", i.e. mutable state, and this prevents equational reasoning. You claim that procedural implementations for side-effect-free functions is OK, but that's quite arguable. Any difference is maybe (pragmatically) insignificant in this case: however, removing "var" altogether (like in Haskell) has considerable advantages (allowing equational reasoning everywhere, for programmers and optimizing compilers).
Scala libraries do so only for efficiency reason.

Answer (score 2):

It is worth pointing out that there is another way of calling `foldLeft` which takes advantages of:

- The ability to use (almost) any Unicode symbol in an identifier
- The feature that if a method name ends with a colon `:`, and is called infix, then the target and parameter are switched

For me this version is much clearer, because I can see that I am folding the `expr` value *into* the `replacements` collection

```
def expand(expr: String, replacements: Traversable[(String, String)]): String = {
  (expr /: replacements) { case (r, (o, n)) => r.replace(o, n) }
}
```

Comment: I know some folks love this abbreviation, but I really try to avoid this kind of thing. I have no intuitive association between division "/" and the fold/reduce operation. If I'm going to use a fold, I'd much rather use `foldLeft` so that someone who doesn't understand it can easily Google for it. I guess it's just a matter of who you think will be reading your code...

Comment: "I have no intuitive association ..." - of course you don't. Why would you? But it's pretty easy to develop one given a few days using it

Comment: Right, but whoever reads my code will also have to spend those few days learning it as well. So it's not a single-time cost, it's a cost for me and for all future readers of my code. I'm much less worried about me, and much more worried about the future readers.

Comment: Syntax error in the example: `expr /: ...` should be `exp /: ...`.

Comment: I disliked this version the first time I saw it, because indeed, for a newcomer, you have no clue of what /: does. That's, somehow, the old debate of symbolic vs. explicit names. Now, I am starting to get used to it... Beside, I admit that, for the uninitiated, `foldLeft` name might not be particularly expressive, either.